# Value not displaying in correct input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 2 row table with `input` fields that does a calculation when I focusout on the first input. The problem I am experiencing is when I focusout on the second row, my new value is displayed in the first row corresponding `input`. I'm not sure why this is happening. I would greatly appreciate your help.

My expectation is when I enter a value in a row input (Cost) and `focusout` the new value should be set in the same row but in the input (New Cost).

```js
function Calculate(element) {
  var dollar = 216.98;
  var id = element.id;
  var oldcost = $(element).val();
  var newcost = oldcost * dollar;
  $("#" + id).closest("tr").find("td #new").val(newcost);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>New Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="old" onfocusout="Caluculate(this)" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" new="new" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="old" onfocusout="Caluculate(this)" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" new="new" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem is you are using same `id` attribute for both elements, use different for each one. Or better yet, use the `element` argument that refers to `this` in a proper way.

Comment: shouldn't `$("#" + id).closest("tr").find("td #new").val(newcost); ` fix that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of id's is kind of messed up. First of all be sure to use an id once in the entire HTML file.
For your usecase better use classes.

Also be sure to type your function names correct ;)

```js
function Calculate(element) {
  var dollar = 216.98;
  var parent = $(element).closest('tr');
  var oldcost = $(element).val();
  var newcost = oldcost * dollar;
  parent.find(".new").val(newcost.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>New Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="old" onfocusout="Calculate(this)" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="new" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="old" onfocusout="Calculate(this)" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="new" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's several issues here. Firstly you're repeating the same `id` attribute which is invalid; they must be unique. I'd suggest using a `class` instead. Secondly, there's is no `new` attribute. I presume that's a typo and should be an `id`, but again see my first point.

Next, the function you defined is named `Calculate()` yet the call is to `Caluculate()`.

Then you should also be using unobtrusive event handlers as `on*` event attributes are very outdated and should be avoided where possible. As you've already included jQuery in the page you can use the `on()` method. The `input` event would seem to be more applicable to your usage as well, especially given it also catches the up/down arrow usage on the number control, although you can change this to `blur` if preferred.

Finally, it's a simply a matter of amending your DOM traversal logic to work with the new classes, like this:

```js
var dollar = 216.98;

$('.old').on('input', function() {
  var oldcost = $(this).val();
  var newcost = oldcost * dollar;
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".new").val(newcost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>New Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="old" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="new" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="old" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="new" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

They have the same ID. You need to make the ID different

Comment: To clarify, an `ID` attribute has to be unique - no other element on the page can have the same `ID`.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant. Or the JS gets confused and poops.

Comment: shouldn't '$("#" + id).closest("tr").find("td #new").val(newcost);' fix the problem because i'm telling it which `id` i'm referring to

Comment: No, because there's multiple `#new` elements (assuming you fix the `new` attribute usage)

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, there is a  a typo.Change `caluculate` to `calculate`
- There must not be the same `id` two elemnts have the same `id`.You could change the id of the first to `old-1` or something different